# append data from dataframe to table with same column name but different datatype

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

I have code which creates the table at first load using df.write.format

EXECUTION 1

```
Schema = 'customer'
TableName= "customerdata"
FolderName = 'subfolder1' #This will change in loop - variable

dfGetCSV =spark.read.format('csv').options(header = True).option('inferSchema', True).load("dbfs:/mnt/rootfolder/"+FolderName+"/*.csv")

dfGetCSV = dfGetCSV.withColumn("FolderName",lit(FolderName)) \
         .withColumn("CREATEDDATE", current_timestamp())

dfGetCSV.write.format("delta").mode("append").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable( """{0}.{1}""".format(Schema, TableName))
```

path that creates dfGetCSV is variable, which loop thru all the subfolders inside root folder. When it executes for first time, it creates delta table with the data inside the csv file in subfolder1. But it fails when it tried to append the data second time from subfolder2 (below)

EXECUTION 2

```
Schema = 'customer'
TableName= "customerdata"
FolderName = 'subfolder2' #this is now pulling all the files from 2nd subfolder in 2nd run

dfGetCSV =spark.read.format('csv').options(header = True).option('inferSchema', True).load("dbfs:/mnt/rootfolder/"+FolderName+"/*.csv")

dfGetCSV = dfGetCSV.withColumn("FolderName",lit(FolderName)) \
         .withColumn("CREATEDDATE", current_timestamp())

dfGetCSV.write.format("delta").mode("append").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable( """{0}.{1}""".format(Schema, TableName))

ERROR : Failed to merge fields 'columnA' and 'columnA'. Failed to merge incompatible data types StringType and IntegerType
```

During the 2nd run , csv has different data in same field, which eventually change the data type. It might be all Null records at very first for ColumnA which makes it string but second time its Int.

Each CSV has about 1000 fields and about 15 GB data.
I want to merge all csv's (under each sublfolder) into one table with added field as subfoldername to track the records coming from which csv. And ColumnA error is just 1 fields example, there are multiple fields like this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this case.

**`Method-1:`**

Get the schema of the existing table and read the new subfolder2 with the existing schema.

```
#get the schema and drop createdate, foldername columns
sch = spark.read.table("""{0}.{1}""".format(Schema, TableName)).drop(*["CREATEDDATE", "FolderName"]).schema

#read the new folder data with the above schema
dfGetCSV =spark.read.format('csv').options(header = True).schema(sch).load("dbfs:/mnt/rootfolder/"+FolderName+"/*.csv")

dfGetCSV = dfGetCSV.withColumn("FolderName",lit(FolderName)) \
         .withColumn("CREATEDDATE", current_timestamp())

dfGetCSV.write.format("delta").mode("append").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable( """{0}.{1}""".format(Schema, TableName))
```

**`Method-2:`**

If you are facing some issues with Method-1 then cast **all the columns as strings** to make things consistent and then write to the table.

By using this way you will be capturing all the columns even though if there are any new columns got added to the data in future.

```
dfGetCSV =spark.read.format('csv').options(header = True).option('inferSchema', True).load("dbfs:/mnt/rootfolder/"+FolderName+"/*.csv")

dfGetCSV = dfGetCSV.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in dfGetCSV.columns]).withColumn("FolderName",lit(FolderName)) \
         .withColumn("CREATEDDATE", current_timestamp())

dfGetCSV.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable( """{0}.{1}""".format(Schema, TableName))
```